# Correct password is not accepted in Yii login

Tags: php, database, yii, authentication

Hi i'm quite new to yii framework, currently trying to establish a login through database authentication. but while im trying to log in i get this error saying

> Please fix the following input errors:
>       Password is incorrect.

but when i check the database table im typing the correct password.

can anybody help me out if this

Heres the Controller

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller

{

public function actions()
{
    return array(

        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),

        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}
public function actionIndex()
{

    $this->render('index');
}


public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('error', $error);
    }
}


public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
            $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

            mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}


public function actionLogin()
{
        $form=new LoginForm;
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $form->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            if($form->validate()  && $form->login()) $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }

            $this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));
}

public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
}
```

}

herers the model

```
<?php

class LoginForm extends CFormModel

{
    public $email;
    public $password;


    private $_identity;

public function rules()
    {
        return array(
        array('email, password', 'required'),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
);
    }
public function attributeLabels()
{
            return array('email'=>'Email Address');
}
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
            if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
                {
                $identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
                $identity->authenticate();
                switch($identity->errorCode)
                {
                    case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
                break;
                    case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                $this->addError('email','Email address is incorrect.');
                break;
        default: // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID
                $this->addError('password','Password is incorrect.');
                break;
                }
            }
    }
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

here the view

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $model LoginForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm  */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Login';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Login',
);
?>
<h1>Login</h1>

<p>Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:</p>

<div class="form">
<?php $myWidget=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div>
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

    <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($form); ?>

    <div>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($form,'email') ?>
    </div>

    <div>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($form,'password') ?>
    </div>

    <div>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

endWidget(); ?>

Comment: is there anybody who is familier with yii login system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your authentication logic inside UserIdentity class not in LoginForm model.

1. LoginForm model ex:-

   ```
    public function authenticate($attribute, $params) {
       if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
          $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);
          if (!$this->_identity->authenticate())
           $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect username or password.');
     }
   }

   public function login() {

     if ($this->_identity === null) {
         $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);
         $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
        $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration);
        return true;
    } else
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. For database authentication you must have to add your authetication logic inside authenticate function using `components\UserIdentity.php`

   ```
   public function authenticate() {

   Yii::app()->getModule('auth')->getModule('user'); #import your module.

   $record = User::model()
           ->findByAttributes(array('email' => CHtml::encode($this->email))); #database call

   if ($record === null)
       $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
   #else if ($record->password !== crypt($this->password, $record->password))
   else if ($record->password !== $this->password)
       $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
   else {
       $this->_uid = $record->user_id;
       $this->setState('title', $record->user_name);
       $this->setState('uid', $this->_uid);
       $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
   }
   return !$this->errorCode;
   ```

   }
3. If you have role based login then you have to add WebUser class in config/main.php.

   ```
   components' => array(
           'user' => array(
               // enable cookie-based authentication
               'class' => 'WebUser',
               'allowAutoLogin' => true,
               'loginUrl'=>array('/site/login'),
               'returnUrl'=>array('/site/index'),
           ),
   }
   ```
4. For role based assess check you have to write `components\WebUser.php` Class -

   ```
    class WebUser extends CWebUser {

   public function checkAccess($operation, $params = array()) {
       if (empty($this->id)) {
           // Not identified => no rights
           return false;
       }
       $role = $this->getState("roles");
       if ($role === '3') {            
           return true; // super admin role has access to everything
       }else if ($role === '1') {            
           return true; // admin(manager) role has access to everything
       }         
       // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
       return ($operation === $role);
   }

   }
   ```

For more information check [Authentication and Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)

Answer (score 0):

In common/models/User.php

```
    public function rules()
   {
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, 
        self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
    ];
    }
```

In this method, set the default 'value'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE
your problem will be solved. I also had the same issue. After changing the value to Active, it worked, because the default value it is setting is 9 and the database considers it an inactive entry that's why it is shoeing incorrect id or password. I hope this helps.