# Setting up a new login for a web application with the help of working Yii demo login

Tags: php, yii, authentication

HI i have a perfectly(configured) working yii login system in its demo application, currrently i dont have much of idea on how to use its login functions( what are the exact scripts or functions to be called ) for my seperate web application, can any body tell me how to place yii directory on my web application and how to call its login functions to use it on my web application

i beleive that protected/useridentity script could do be a major script in this process, therefore following is the autheticate() function of it,

```
$user = tusers::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
            if ($user===null) { // No user found!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            } else if ($user->password !== ($this->password) ) { // Invalid password!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            } else { // Okay!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            // Store the usertype in a session:
            $this->setState('usertype', $user->usertype);
```

Comment: any yii experts out there

Comment: did you create a new web app?

Comment: yes i did... i want to know actually what should be the login form "action" of my new web application

Comment: by default the actionLogin() is called in the site controller, are you getting any error?

Comment: Your solution is correct, you won't have to do anything further to the demo app to get this work, besides setting the id field, as shown here : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.auth.  I assume that you will later replace password with an encrypted password mechanism, right?

Comment: Check this link for more information:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051939/correct-password-is-not-accepted-in-yii-login/26052542#26052542