# Yii login error "CWebUser.usertype"

Tags: php, yii, authentication

Hi im trying use Yii login scripts to make my websites login system. i have currently configured the yii login in its demo application according to the way i want. but when i try to login using yii from my own website login page it gives an error sayinh

> Property "CWebUser.usertype" is not defined.

can anybody help me over thing

this is how i make the call in my login page

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
            <div class="well no-padding">
                <form action="Login_yii/index.php?r=site/login" id="login-form" class="smart-form client-form">
                    <header>
                        Sign In
                    </header>

                    <fieldset>

                        <section>
                            <label class="label">Username</label>
                            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                                <input type="text" name="LoginForm[username]" id="username">
                                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Please enter the username</b></label>
                        </section>

                        <section>
                            <label class="label">Password</label>
                            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                                <input type="password" name="LoginForm[password]" id="password">
                                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Enter your password</b> </label>
                            <div class="note">
                                <a href="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>/forgotpassword.php">Forgot password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <section>
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked="">
                                <i></i>Stay signed in</label>
                        </section>
                    </fieldset>
                    <footer>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" su>
                            Sign in
                        </button>
                    </footer>
                </form>
```

Useridentity

```
    <?php

class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;


            $user = users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
            if ($user===null) { // No user found!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            } else if ($user->password !== ($this->password) ) { // Invalid password!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            } else { // Okay!
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            // Store the usertype in a session:
            $this->setState('usertype', $user->usertype);
            //die($user->usertype);
            //$file = "log.txt";
    //$write = ("time_s ".$user->usertype."\n");//
    //file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);
            //$this->_id = $user->id;
            }
            return !$this->errorCode;



    public function getId()
                {
                return $this->_id;
                }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the useridentity file

Comment: there is something wrong in your useridentity.php file, find that in protected/components/UserIdentity.php

Comment: ok guys i added the user identity now!!!!! u can have a look

Comment: You are referencing usertype before the user is logged in

Comment: I have given answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051939/correct-password-is-not-accepted-in-yii-login/26052542#26052542

Comment: In your model users you don't have property/column 'usertype', can you update your question with model 'users' code (protected/models/users.php)?